# Sort nested objects (multiple times) by strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, object, lodash

I have two, *very* nested objects - and I'd like to reorder them based on whether they contain a string or not. Ideally, I'd like to reorder them multiple times over, depending on whether they have any number of strings.

I'd like reorder them by one category, and then another - sort the list twice (I understand that's not a great way of saying it).

**Top level Objects**

```
[
  { 
    name: { en: 'Even Mini-er Cooper (test)' },
    categories: { en: [Array] },
  },
  {
    name: { en: 'Mini Cooper' },
    categories: { en: [Array] }, 
  }
]
```

**How to get to the things I want to compare**

```
products.map(o => o.fields.categories.en.map(o => o.fields.name));

[ 
  [ 
    { en: '13+ / Movies/Animations/SciFi - Cartoons' },
    { en: '13+ /  Movies/Animations/SciFi' } 
  ],
  [ 
    { en: '13+ / Coding & Gaming' },
    { en: '13+ / Coding & Gaming - Boost' } 
  ] 
]
```

I've looked at lodash's `_.orderBy` and `_.sortBy` - but I can't see how I can add my search param.

Thanks for any insights you may have

Comment: What is the expected output and the exact input?

Comment: "Sorting the list twice" doesn't really make sense, but if you mean "sort once, then sort items that were equal in the first sort" - then that can be done. Regardless of the nesting, this should be possible using the `lodash` functions you mention, but there is too much ambiguity in the current question to help beyond that. If you include a sample input/output (or several), I'm confident we'll be able to help